# Spring Profiles on method level With Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/develop")
@Configuration
public class DevelopController {
    
    @Resource(name = "smsService")
    private SmsService smsService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/verification/selectAuthVerifyCode", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = Constant.APP_JSON)
    @Bean
    @Profile({"local"})
    public @ResponseBody AuthVerifyCodeO selectAuthVerifyCode(
              @RequestParam(value="callingCode", required=true) String callingCode
          ,  @RequestParam(value="regionPhoneNumber", required=true) String regionPhoneNumber
            ) throws Exception {
        
        AuthVerifyCodeO result = new AuthVerifyCodeO();
        
        result = smsService.selectAuthVerifyCode(callingCode, regionPhoneNumber);
            
        return result;
    } 
}
```

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'selectAuthVerifyCode' defined in class path resource [com/test/scheduler/executor/DevelopController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'selectAuthVerifyCode' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate
```

I want to use `@Profile` on method-level but an error occurred
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: That method doesn't make sense. Why is it both an `@Bean` method and a controller method. That doesn't make sense. Nor does the fact that this is an `@configuration` **and** an `@RestController`.

Comment: Can you try removing the curly braces - @Profile("local")?

Comment: it doesn't matter curly braces

Comment: i must use @RestController

Comment: i removed @ Configuration and @ Bean annotation is it possible?

Comment: The error occurs because it annotated with `@Bean` in that case all the arguments to the method will be injected since the arguments are Strings you're getting `No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate`

Comment: As stated this bean doesn't make sense. `@Profile` is only usable on `@Bean` methods or on types. Instead of trying to make this work rather ask the question what you are trying to achieve with this or rather the use-case you are trying to solve.

Comment: I just want use selectAuthVerifyCode method only on 'local'

Comment: Why? It is a controller, if this controller should be only active for that profile, you should place the annotation on the controller not the method. However why do you want this to be only available in local. Is it a controller or part of configuration as that totally isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming, you didn't set the profile with Spring context. You need to add the following in the execution context.

```
@Autowired
private ConfigurableEnvironment env;
env.setActiveProfiles("local");
```

Comment: i already set on Tomcat launch config
-Dspring.profiles.active=local

Comment: @JungGa  Starting logs shows the profile it is taken for execution. Verify is it `local1` or `default`?

Comment: 2020-12-10 15:59:08.352  INFO 49192 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.l.context.config.ServletConfigurator   : The following profiles are active: local

Comment: @JungGa , Looks like you added additional details and code in question. See the comment from M.Deinum. He makes a point.